# Scroll page by roll click on very hight page - not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, scroll

https://y2z8w0l0vz.codesandbox.io/

I have div, and child div:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;">
   <div style="width:100px;height:500000px;"></div>
</div>
```

When I try scroll page, by click middle, roll click, scrolling doesn't work always.

I noticed that scrolling on the page doesn't work 
correctly, when the page is scrolls to the middle of 'height'. If I scroll page when is scrolls on top, scrolling working.

This problem is on Chrome, Yandex (chrome engine), on Firefox scrolling work good on all 'height' of page.

how I can resolve this strange problem with scrolling?

Comment: What do you mean by "I try scroll page, by click middle, roll click" ? do you mean click middle-click + drag mouse ?

Comment: @PopHip I think that he is talking about the Scroll wheel , when you click on it you can scroll the page to the bottom or top when you move your cursor in the corresponding direction.

Comment: @PopHip Yes, click middle-click + drag mouse

Comment: I know that 500000px of height is big size, but I'm using React-virtualized to scrolll big table, and I found this issue i Chrome browser.